# Двоеточие перед картинкой

Tags: пунктуация, двоеточие, оформление-текста, редактура

Хоть кто-нибудь знает тут, можно ли ставить двоеточие перед картинками?

Например, в инструкции говорится нажать на кнопку там-то: [изображение расположения кнопки]

или

Далее переходим в меню и нажимаем на раздел Название:

[изображение раздела в меню]

Comment: Следует определиться с наклонением, оно не может скакать от павелительного к «переходим и нажимаем». Первое требует строго соответствующего знака, который в большом количестве не воспринимается. Двоеточие как знак препинания подчинён правилам пунктуации. **Всю инструкцию можно воспринимать как одну фразу с перечислением действий через запятую**.

Comment: Наклонение скачет от п**О**велительного, т.к. эти примеры вообще не связаны.

"Всю инструкцию можно воспринимать как одну фразу с перечислением действий через запятую" - то есть знак после предложения перед картинкой вообще не нужен?